# как создать функцию, которая бы генерировала несколько паролей в php

Tags: php

Доброе утро, я пытаюсь создать функцию, которая будет генерировать несколько паролей. Получается сделать только генерация одного пароля, а хотелось бы несколько.Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать.

```
$kkk = generate_password($chislo);
 
  function generate_password($number)
  {
  $pass = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++)
    {
    $index = rand(0, 9);
    $pass .= $index;
      
    }
return $pass;
      }
 
    echo "<br><br><br><br>".$kkk;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Заведи массив
2. В цикле вызывай данную функцию и результат складывай в этот массив.
3. PROFIT